# Casual way of asking someone how they found or calculated a number?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

I am doing some calculations for a work project, and I guess that I have made a mistake in finding Flow Rate. I want to ask a coworker in a casual manner that where he/she get the flow rate from. This is not to undermine their work but to ask them to help me understand their method.
I am looking for a phrasal verb that has a sense of finding, calculating and comming up with.

Comment: What words have you considered already, and why do they not meet your needs? This information would help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask your colleague

> How do you **determine** the flow rate?

and if you want to make it clear you are not trying to undermine them add

> I seem to have made a mistake.

Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/determine)

> **determine**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **2** Ascertain or establish exactly by research or calculation.
> *the inquest is entrusted with the task of determining the cause of death*
>
> **2.1** (Mathematics) Specify the value, position, or form of (a mathematical or geometrical object) uniquely.
> *Weil's work on polynomial equations led to questions on what properties of a geometric object can be determined purely algebraically.*

Comment: Also there's a slight difference between "How do you?" and "How did you?". "How do you" is closer to "How does one" and would be asking more generally about their method. "How did you" would be asking how they found the rate in some particular past instance.

Comment: @ColleenV when I first posted this as a comment I put "did you" then realised that the asker wants to know the method used generally.

Comment: I did the same thing mentally when I read your answer, so I thought it might be worth pointing out since the OP seems like they might be a non-native English speaker who would appreciate knowing the nuance there.

Comment: Does "How you determine the flow rate?" something that native would find normal to hear in daily conversation? I want to stand somewhere between not to be stilted or too casual

Comment: In an environment where flow rates are considered, this usage isn't stilted, but you could consider "figure out" to be more casual (and a phrasal verb).

Comment: And among friends and classmates i’d probably just say, “How’d you get the flow rate?  I couldn’t do it.”